# How to get value from select and use it in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select

I'm starting a little project in rails and I'm trying to make something like that:

```
<%= f.label :Zgłoszenie_do_działu %>
<%= f.collection_select :dzial_id, Dzial.all, :id, :nazwa, prompt: "Wybierz" %>


<%= f.label :id_pracownik %><br/>
<%= f.collection_select :pracownikid, User.find_by_dzial_id(:dzial_id), :nazwa, prompt:"Wybierz" %>
```

I want to get ID of "dzial" from the first select and use it to display in the second select IDs or names of users, that belong to choosen "dzial". Like you can see I was trying to make something, but anything worked for me. If it isn't possible I would be thankful, if anybody would show me how to deal with it.

Comment: you can do it using Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do understand you properly, you have the following usecase: On your page you select a dzial and after that the second select field has to show all it's User ids.

**Without refreshing the page**

If you want to do this without refreshing the page, you can't really do it the 'rails way'. You could use for example jQuery to do an asynchronous call on change of the first select field. Then you can use the result of that call to update the second select field.

**With refreshing the page**

If you want to do this by only using ruby-on-rails you could trigger a refresh on the change of the first select or simply create a submit button. Then you can set the `dzial_id` parameter and use it to fill the second select field like you are already doing in your example.

**Edit** 
I forgot to mention how to get the value from the select field.

- By using jQuery, you could use `$('#dzial_select').val()`
- By refreshing the page, you might want to create two seperate forms